# no indentation at hyphenated word in quote environment

Tags: indentation, quoting

I'm typesetting a whole bible and I'm trying to reproduce some special quotes of it using the quote environment and some macros. These quotes have indentation when there is a new line (`\\`), and the hyphenated word are unindented.

Here is an image depicting the desired effect:

[image]

Here is the minimal working example that shows the real output (please ignore other format details). Again, the first line of the quote is longer than the rest, but the word "embarazos:" should be unindented. The rest is ok.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, twocolumn,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\partname}{Libro de}} 

\newlength{\vl}
\newcounter{Verso}
\newcounter{Cap}
\setcounter{Verso}{1}
\setcounter{Cap}{1}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\jChapter}[1]{\par\bigskip\lettrine{{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}{}}

\newcommand{\vs}{%
\settowidth{\vl}{\tiny{\arabic{Verso}}}%
\textsuperscript{\tiny{\arabic{Verso}}}% 
\stepcounter{Verso}%
}%

\newcommand{\ch}{%
\arabic{Cap}%
\chapter*{\theCap}%
\jChapter{\theCap}%
\stepcounter{Cap}%
\setcounter{Verso}{1}%
}%

\newcommand{\cita}[1]{\begin{quote}\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}#1\end{quote}}
\newcommand{\cm}[1]{\flqq#1\frqq}
\newcommand{\pr}[1]{¿#1?}   
\begin{document}
\part*{Génesis}
\section*{Primer relato de la creación}
\ch

\vs{}A la mujer le dijo: \cita{\cm{Tantas haré tus fatigas cuantos sean tus embarazos:\\con dolor parirás a los hijos.\\Hacia tu marido ira tu 
apetencia,\\y él te dominará.}}

\end{document}
```

How should I modify my code in order to get the desired result?

Comment: I am very confused as the picture shows all of the lines of the quote indented _except_ for the hyphenated word. I think That is what you want, that any wrapped lines (whether at a hyphen or not) are not indented.

Comment: You should at `\parindent <length>` to your `quote` environment'. I think, in general, the way you are inputting the biblical texts could be improved/simplified. The most obvious problem is the reliance on `\\`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, you're right. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: You say 'but the word "embarazos:" should be indented' but it _is_ indented by the code you post.  Presumably you want it like the picture (and my answer) _not_ indented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Updated answer after OP posted more information about intend look of cited/quoted material. Provided further updates to address additional questions.)

If I understand your objectives correctly, using a `quote` environment is not the way to go -- the `quote` environments indents its material on both sides, not just on the left.

Instead, I suggest setting up an environment that increases the value of `\parindent` locally. Inside the new environment, use blank lines to start the (typographic) equivalent of new paragraphs.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, twocolumn,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}%{mathpazo}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\partname}{Libro de}} 

\newlength{\vl}
\newcounter{Verso}
\newcounter{Cap}
\setcounter{Verso}{1}
\setcounter{Cap}{1}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\jChapter}[1]{\par\bigskip\lettrine{{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}{}}

\newcommand{\vs}{%
\settowidth{\vl}{\tiny{\arabic{Verso}}}%
\textsuperscript{\tiny{\arabic{Verso}}}% 
\stepcounter{Verso}%
}%

\newcommand{\ch}{%
\arabic{Cap}%
\chapter*{\theCap}%
\jChapter{\theCap}%
\stepcounter{Cap}%
\setcounter{Verso}{1}%
}%

\newenvironment{cita}%
  {\begingroup%
   \addtolength{\parindent}{1em}%
   \flqq}%
  {\frqq
   \par
   \endgroup}

\newcommand{\cm}[1]{\flqq#1\frqq}
\newcommand{\pr}[1]{¿#1?}   
\begin{document}
\part*{Génesis}
\section*{Primer relato de la creación}
\ch

\vs{}A la mujer le dijo:

\begin{cita}%
Tantas haré tus fatigas cuantos sean tus embarazos:

con dolor parirás a los hijos.

Hacia tu marido ira tu apetencia,

y él te dominará.%
\end{cita}

(More text after \texttt{cita} environment, starting with normal 
indentation of first line of paragraph)
\hrule % just to illustrate full width of text block


\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh you might be right. (Although given the clarity of the question it is hard to know:-) I think I'll delete my answer anyway.

Comment: THanks for your question, but the whole quote isn't indented. According to the screenshot I posted, the whole quote should be indented, except the hyphenated word.

I gave you a vote anyway ;)

Comment: @Charlie - It might be helpful if you posted a larger screenshot that shows more context. (In the currently-posted screenshot, the strings "el hombre" and "sos" both appear not to be indented at all. A wider screenshot might reveal that this impression is incorrect.) Please also indicate by *how much* you would like the quoted material to be indented on the left. There should be no indentation on the right, correct?

Comment: @Mico, there's no indentation on the right side. Please consider the larger screenshot of my answer.

Comment: @Charlie - I've updated my answer to reflect the information you've given in the comments. Let me just remark that the new screenshot you've provided does *not* indicate that the "quoted" material should be left-indented differently from the surrounding material.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - My updated answer generates output that looks very much like the one given in your (currently deleted) answer. Let me know if you want to resurrect [term chosen deliberately, in view of the material being typeset...] your answer, and I'll delete mine...

Comment: @Mico no your markup is far cleaner than I suggested.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for your updated answer. The code you posted almost solves the problem, the only thing is that the indentation is too big and the first line of every paragraph is also indented (not quote). It works in the minimal example, but it produces a bigger indentation in the whole document.

Comment: @Charlie - To change the amount of indentation, just modify the second argument of the instruction `\addtolength{\parindent}{1em}`. Are you using the `cita` environment the way I do in my example, i.e., with blank line after every line of the citation?

Comment: @Charlie - Would you like me to delete this answer? I've honestly tried to come up with a workable solution. However, you seem to indicate that my answer does not work for you.

Comment: @Mico, please don't delete the answer. I'm using the cita environment as you indicated. So, it seems that this \addtolength command modifies permanently the ammount of indentation. Is there a way to make \addtolength to modify the indentation only inside the environment?

Comment: @Charlie - I honestly can't explain what may be going on in your TeX system. I've posted a bit of additional code to illustrate that the "normal amount" of paragraph indentation is restored after the `cita` environment -- as defined in the example itself -- ends.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Mico. Despite really small indentation issues, I marking my question as solved, because the quotes behaves almost the way they appear in the old bible.